# synchronized timer on multiple networked computers

Tags: php, javascript, flash, macos, actionscript

i am working on an art/programming project that involves using a lab of 30 imacs. i want to synchronize them in a way that will allow me to execute a script on each of them at the very same time.

the final product is in flash player, but if i am able to synchronize an type of data signal through a web page, i'd be able to run the script at the same time. so far my attempts have all had fatal flaws.

the network i'm using is somewhat limited. i don't have admin privileges but i don't think it matters really. i log into my user account on all 30 imacs, run the page or script so i can run my wares.

my first attempts involved running flash player directly.
at first i tried using the system time and had the script run every two minutes. this wasn't reliable because even though the time in my user account is synced there is discrepancy between imacs. a quarter of a second is too much even.
my next try involved having one mac acting as the host which writes a variable to a text file. all other 29 flash players checked for changes in this file multiple times a second. this didn't work. it would work with 3 or 4 computers but then would be flaky. the strain on the server was too great and flash is just unreliable. i figured i'd try using local shared objects but that wasn't reliable. i tried having the host computer write to 30 files and have each mac read only one each but that didn't work either. i tried using local connection but it is not made for more than two computers.

my next try involved having a php server time script run on my web server and have the 30 computers check the time of that files nearly 30 seconds. i don't think my hosting plans supports this because the server would just stop working after a few seconds. too many requests or something. 
although i haven't had success with a remote server, it will probably be more reliable with another clever method.

i do have one kludge solution as a last straw (you might laugh): i would take an audio wire and buy 29 audio splitters and plug all of them in. then i would run flash player locally and have it execute when it hears a sound. i've done this before. all you have to do is touch the other end of the wire and the finger static is enough to set it off.

what can i do now? i've been working on this project on and off for a year and just want to get it going. if i can get a web page synchronized on 30 computers in a lab i could just pass data to flash and it would likely work. i'm more confident with a remote server but if i can do it using the local mac network, that would be great.

Comment: so all 30 machines are on local private network right?  how are you running the scripts?  is it by timer or is it by manual command from you? Seems like you need socket connection.

Comment: yes these 30 imacs are a part of a larger lan. 
i've tried many methods. i've tried by timer and manual command. none of my methods have worked. ideally it should run from manual command. the scripts run in actionscript in flash. for the php server method, i had the swf uploaded to the web server and it would interact with the php (reading it) using actionscript. 

at the very least, the code would run separately and then at the same time would send data to flash to know to start.

Comment: i actually worked on something similar to this.  i used socket connection w/ server clients interaction.  local connection on flash is really flaky at times. i can conjure something up tomorrow just check back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is how i approached my problem using socket connection with flash and php.  Basically, first you setup a client script that is to be installed on all 30 imac 'client' machines.  lets assume all machines are on a private network.  When these clients are activated they are connected to a server(php), by using socket.  The php server script would have an ip and a port that these clients connects to, handles client connections pool, message routing and etc, and the server will be running at all time.  The socket connection allows the server-client interaction by sending messages back and forth, and these messages can trigger things to do.  You should read up more on socket connection/server client interaction.  This is just a little summary of how i got my project done.

[Simple tutorial on socket/server client connection using php and flash](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flash8/php5sockets_flash8.htm)

Comment: i will try to implement sockets into my project in the next few days. i hope this works! thanks big time!